# shapeshifter-dispatcher starts only in obfs2 mode

Tags: proxy, pluggable-transports, obfsproxy, openvpn, obfs4proxy

I am trying to start shapeshifter-dispatcher as a standalone proxy on both a server and a client machine to tunnel an OpenVPN connection. However it appears to be able to start only if I select the pluggable transport obfs2, failing when I select others like scramblesuit, meek, obfs4 etc.
The following command is what I use on the server:

```
shapeshifter-dispatcher -server -transparent -ptversion 2 -transports obfs2 -state state -bindaddr obfs2-MY.LAN.IP.HERE:500 -orport 127.0.0.1:1194
```

Despite an error claiming I don't have an extended OR address, it starts fine. However when I change the obfs2 text with obfs4, I get the following error:

```
launching
obfs4-192.168.1.74:500
Error resolving Extended OR address  missing port in address
ServerSetup obfs4-192.168.1.74:500 {[{obfs4 192.168.1.74:500 map[]}] 127.0.0.1:1194 <nil> }
bindaddr {obfs4 192.168.1.74:500 map[]}
launched false []
```

Also there's no way I am able to enable a more advanced logging to obtain more information.

As far as I get, shapeshifter-dispatcher seems to be the heir of obfsproxy but it's still a bit crude and in alpha stage. Am I right?

EDIT: I managed to get the log to work, and this is what I get:

```
2017/04/15 12:58:00 [NOTICE]: dispatcher-0.0.7-dev - launched
2017/04/15 12:58:00 [INFO]: shapeshifter-dispatcher - initializing transparent proxy
2017/04/15 12:58:00 [INFO]: shapeshifter-dispatcher - initializing UDP transparent proxy
2017/04/15 12:58:00 [INFO]: shapeshifter-dispatcher - initializing server transport listeners
2017/04/15 12:58:00 [ERROR]: obfs4 transport missing cert argument: map[]
```

Comment: Nothing to do with Tor at all.

Comment: True, but I thought shapeshifter-dispatcher's application goes beyond tor as stated on pluggabletransports.info. Also, I got pointed here exactly by such website, which I believe is the official reference for the project.